# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'void' C# WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have this link to send in gmail:

```cs
"<br />< a href = '"
 + HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=",false)
 + "' >Click here to change your password.</a>";
```

When I do this code it gives me this error

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'void' C# WebMethod

Someone help please?

Comment: What do you think Response.Redirect is for?

Comment: `Response.Redirect` does not produce a result. It causes the browser to redirect. It looks like you think it creates a URL string but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` doesn't return a string.

I suppose you wanted to do:

```
"<br /><a href='CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode='>Click here to change your password.</a>";
```